# 2 stage least Squares as an Instrumental variable estimator

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables

$\mathbf{X}_{n \times K}= \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{x}'_1 \\
       \cdots \\
       \mathbf{x}'_n
     \end{bmatrix}$
$\mathbf{Z}_{n \times L}= \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{z}'_1 \\
       \cdots \\
       \mathbf{z}'_n
     \end{bmatrix}$

where $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}$ are instruments, and  $\{\mathbf{z}_i\}$ are the variables(some of which are endogenous).

If I regress each $z_{il}$ on $\mathbf{x}_i$ define the fitted value as $\hat{z}_{il}$, i'll get  $\hat{\mathbf{z}}_l=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{z}_l$.

So, $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}_{n \times L}= \begin{bmatrix}
      \hat{\mathbf{z}}'_1 \\   \cdots \\   \hat{ \mathbf{z}}'_n
     \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{z}_1 &&   \cdots &&   \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{z}_n
     \end{bmatrix}= \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z}$

The IV estimator formula, when using these newly created instruments is

$(\hat{\mathbf{Z}}'\mathbf{Z})^{-1}\hat{\mathbf{Z}}'\mathbf{y}=((\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z})'\mathbf{Z})^{-1}(\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z})'\mathbf{y}$ which is the 2SLS estimator.

My question is how can we be sure that $\hat{\mathbf{z}}_{l}$ are instruments?

Edit: Here is the original text.[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your notation/set-up. Where are the coefficients to be estimated? Also it seems to me that you should refer to the $\widehat{\textbf{z}}$ as fitted values from the first stages rather than "new instruments". If so then I'm not quite sure anymore what the actual question is. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @Andy I've put up the original text. My doubt is «how can we prove that the new variables created by the regression of the data on instruments, create new instruments?» How do we prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by the question " How do we know that they are instruments", you mean "how do we know that they are orthogonal to the error term?", then:

We have assumed that $$E\big(\mathbf {X'} \mathbf u\big) = 0$$
For orthogonality of the fitted values we want

$$E\big(\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u\big) = E\left[\left(\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf Z \right)'\mathbf u\right] = ? \;0$$

Applying the transpose operation we get

$$E\left[\mathbf {Z'} \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}' \mathbf u \right] = ?\;0$$
As such it does not look like we are permitted to separate the matrix product and take separate expected values -after all, $\mathbf Z$ is not independent of $\mathbf u$, so even with the projection matrix of the original instruments "in the middle", how can we break the expected value?

The subtlety here is that we obtain the expected value as a limiting case of the sample size going to infinity (because it is then that we need orthogonality so that consistency is preserved). In other words, we *first* take probability limits and *then* "arrive" asymptotically at expected values. But probability limits distribute irrespective of independence. The IV estimator with the fitted values is

$$\hat \beta_{IV} = \beta + \left(\mathbf {\hat Z'}\mathbf {\hat Z}\right)^{-1}\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u = \beta + \left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'}\mathbf {\hat Z}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u\right)$$

and

$${\rm plim}(\hat \beta_{IV} - \beta) = {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'}\mathbf {\hat Z}\right)^{-1} {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u\right)$$

As usual a separate assumption is that the first ${\rm plim}$ converges to something non-zero and finite. So we are interested in the second ${\rm plim}$,

$${\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u\right) = {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {Z'} \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}' \mathbf u \right)$$

Note that we already have one $1/n$ factor so we can write

$${\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {\hat Z'} \mathbf u\right) = {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {Z'} \mathbf{X}\right)\left(\frac 1n\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf{X}' \mathbf u \right)$$

and now we can separate ${\rm plim}$'s again

$$... = {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf {Z'} \mathbf{X}\right){\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}{\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf{X}' \mathbf u \right)$$

Again the first two matrix products are assumed to converge to something non-zero and finite, so we focus on the last one, for which given the other assumptions of the model we have that

$$ {\rm plim}\left(\frac 1n\mathbf{X}' \mathbf u \right) = E\big(\mathbf {X'} \mathbf u\big) = 0$$

-zero by the orthogonality of the original instruments. So the fitted values are indeed valid instruments, if the original instruments are valid instruments.

Comment: I'm always learning. :) thanks

How would I go if I wanted to prove that the new instruments were correlated with the observed vectors. What condition would I impose on $Cov(\hat{\mathbf{Z}},\mathbf{Z})$?

Comment: $E(\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i \mathbf{z}'_i)$ being full column rank, right?

Comment: Could you please give me some insight on how to prove the generalization of the condition that the instruments must be correlated with the regressors? Maybe it's something trivial, that I'm missing.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea If they are not correlated then regressing the regressors on the instruments will give you nada, so this "indirect" IV method won't work. In the more basic case, where we start from the orthogonality condition $$E(\mathbf X'\mathbf u)=0$$ $$\implies ... (\mathbf X'\mathbf Z)^{-1}\mathbf X'\mathbf y=\beta$$ do you think the matrix $(\mathbf X'\mathbf Z)$ is invertible if $\mathbf X'$ and $\mathbf Z$ are orthogonal?

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused with the notation, due to my lack of knowledge, so I'll stick to Hayashi notation. In the the simple case of IV, we would still need to assume that $E(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$ is full rank to reach the formula for beta. But how from $\mathbf{x}_i$ being orthogonal, can I prove that $E(\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i\mathbf{z}'_i$ is full rank? ($\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i$ are the new instruments)

Comment: I think I now understand your comment. What I thinkn that Hayashi was saying in this part of the book was that by constructing new variables by regressing known regressors $z_{il}$ on the known instruments $\mathbf{x}_i$, and then create a new variable $\hat{z}_{il}$ as the fitted value of this regression. He states that because these new variables are also intruments, then we can use the IV formula, and do a substitution in it to obtain the 2SLS estimator. In my answer below, I don't think we need to assume that the new variables(the fitted values)are correlated.

Comment: You write "I don't think  we need to assume that the new variables (the fitted values) are correlated". Correlated with what?

Comment: with the original regressors. We can deduce that from using the assumption that the original regressors are correlated with the 'old' instruments (x's). I think I do just that below...

Comment: So you are saying that $\hat Z$ is (or can be) uncorrelated with $Z$, do I understand correctly?

Comment: No. What I am saying is that they are correlated, but we cannot assume that. We have to prove it, and I tried to below.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on section 9.2 of Hamilton's Time Series, with suitable adaptations. This complements the answer by @AlecosPapadopoulos

I'll try to prove that $E(\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$ is full column rank (the new instruments are correlated with the regressors.

To generate the new instruments, we first need to use OLS on the following equation:

$$ z_{il}=\mathbf{x}'_i\beta_l+\epsilon_{il} $$, where $z_{il}$ is element $i,l$ of matrix $\mathbf{Z}$.

By OLS, we know that $\hat{\beta}_l=(\sum^N_{i=1}\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}'_i)^{-1}(\sum^N_{i=1}\mathbf{x}_iz_{il})$.

So, $\hat{\mathbf{z}}'_i=\mathbf{x}'_i\hat{\beta}$, where $\hat{\beta}=(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_1 \dots \hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_L)= (\sum \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}'_i )^{-1}(\sum \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$

From $1/N \sum_i\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i\mathbf{z}'_i=\hat{\beta}'\frac{\sum \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i}{N}=(\sum \mathbf{z}_i\mathbf{x}'_i)(\sum \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}'_i )^{-1}(\sum \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)/N$

If we do the plim on both sides, we get $E(\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)=E(\mathbf{z}_i\mathbf{x}'_i)(E(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}'_i))^{-1}E(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$

Now in the IV setting $K=L$ (numb.regressors=numb.instruments), so $E(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$ is a square matrix and by assumption it's full column rank (the x's are also instruments). The $E(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}'_i)$ is invertible, since we're also assuming conditional homoskedasticity, and together with the assumption of $E(\mathbf{g}_i\mathbf{g}'_i)$ being non-singular , where $\mathbf{g}_i=\mathbf{x}_i\epsilon_i$ is a martingale sequence.Therefore, $E(\hat{\mathbf{z}}_i\mathbf{z}'_i)$ is invertible.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Do you agree with this answer?

Comment: That the fitted values of a dependent variable derived from a linear regression are correlated with the dependent variable itself (assuming correct specification of course), is a very basic fact of linear regression, and easily provable, and has nothing particular to do with Instrumental Variables. It doesn't even need asymptotics to be shown, just consider the covariance of $\hat Z$ and $Z$. Also it appears that you "equate" "full column rank" with "correlation". Why? _Extreme_ correlation (i.e. _exact_ linear dependence), would lead to deficient rank, if anything.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, reading page 200-201 from Hayashi, he states that the assumption of $E(x_iz'_i)$ being full column rank is a generalization of the case of one non-constant regressor/one non-constant instrument. How would we calculate the covariance of $\hat{Z}$ and $Z$ in this case?